# How can I get data when I search using relationship eloquent laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

How to get value relationships in eloquent laravel

here is my model  Food

```
class food extends Model 
{ 
  protected $table = 'food';
  protected $fillable = [
        'name'
   ];
  public function foodType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Food_type::class, 'food_type_id');
    }
}
```

here is my  food_type model

```
class food_type extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'food_type';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'description'
    ];

    public function getFood()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Food::class);
    }
}
```

I want to get food_type.name in food_type table .How can I query like this

```
$search = $request->search
$food = Food::with(['foodType'])
                ->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('foodType.name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')->get();
```

Comment: What is the query giving you ? You are really savage, you are writing a class like Snake Case instead of CamelCase... and see that the "belongsTo" says" `Food_type` and your class is named `food_type`... use always CamelCase.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relationships are not included with joins when you use eager loading.  Review the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) as it covers how to use whereHas and other relationship related methods.

```
$food = Food::with(['foodType'])
                ->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhereHas('foodType' function($q) {
                      $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
                })
                ->get();
```